# What about $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\text{gd}(\log(xy))}{1-xy}dxdy,$ where $\text{gd}(z)$ is the Gudermannian function?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This morning I was thinking in integrals of the kind $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\text{Numerator}(x,y)}{1-xy}\,dxdy,$$ where $\text{Numerator}(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ involving special functions. Then as a particular case of these I am trying to think if

> **Question.** Is it possible to calculate an expression (a series, a closed-form involving special functions or a very good approximation) for $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\text{gd}(\log(xy))}{1-xy}\,dxdy,$$ where $\text{gd}(z)$ is the Gudermannian function? What are your calculations and approach? If you don't know this special function see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html). **Thanks in advance.**

Notice that I've choose this example with the purpose to combine with the expression involving the Guermannian function and the inverse tangent function, $(4)$ in previous reference. Then using a Cauchy product I wrote 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\text{gd}(\log(xy))}{1-xy}\,dxdy=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^k\frac{(-1)^l}{(2l+1)(l+k+2)^2}-\frac{\pi^3}{12}.$$ On the other hand [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) knows how calculate indefinite integrals as

`int arctan(xy)/(1-xy)dx`

but with my standard time of computation and code I am not able to calculate a closed-form for our integral in the Question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $\text{gd}\log z=2\arctan z-\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence
$$ \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{\text{gd}\log(xy)}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy=2\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{\arctan(xy)}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\iint_{(0,1)^2}(xy)^n\,dx\,dy$$
where the last integral clearly equals $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Since
$$ \arctan(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$
we have
$$ 2\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{\arctan(xy)}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy = 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\sum_{m\geq 2n+2}\frac{1}{m^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{12}-\color{blue}{2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n H_{2n+1}^{(2)}}{2n+1}} $$
and the whole problem boils down to evaluating the blue series. We have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} H_{n}^{(2)} z^n = \frac{\text{Li}_2(z)}{1-z},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0} 2\,H_{2n+1}^{(2)} z^{2n+1} = \frac{\text{Li}_2(z)}{1-z}-\frac{\text{Li}_2(-z)}{1+z} $$
hence the evaluation of the blue series is equivalent to the computation of the integral
$$ \frac{1}{i}\int_{0}^{i}\left(\frac{\text{Li}_2(z)}{z(1-z)}-\frac{\text{Li}_2(-z)}{z(1+z)}\right)\,dz$$
which by partial fraction decomposition and the functional identities for the dilogarithm and trilogarithm equals:

$$ 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n H_{2n+1}^{(2)}}{2n+1}=\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi^3}{24}+G \log 2-\frac{\pi}{8}\log^2(2)+4\,\text{Im }\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)} $$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant.

Comment: Many thanks it is incredible. I am going to study your proof.